# How do I view "sub process" specific memory info in Task Manager (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, memory, task-manager

On some machines, I am able to view the memory consumption of individual "sub processes" of an app in Task manager, like so with Google Chrome:

[image: Task Manager showing memory consumption for Google Chrome "sub processes"]

On other machines, I do not get "sub process" specific memory info, and instead can only see the memory consumption of the app as a whole.

[image: Task Manager not showing memory consumption for Google Chrome "sub processes"]

Does anyone know how I can configure windows, my user, or other such that I can see "sub process" specific memory info?

Comment: Can you give more information about which Windows versions are not showing full process information? I have never encountered that before. If you are looking for a better Task manager, look no further than Microsoft's [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Comment: You can also right click on one of those sub-processes and click "Go to details", which will highlight the process in the "Detauls" tab. This tab *always* displays every process running and memory usage for each of them. One more thing, Google Chrome specifically has its own task manager (use [Shift + Esc]) to handle its own sub-processes.

Comment: Thanks for both of your suggestions! @harrymc, aside from "Windows 10" what's the sort of information you're looking for? Unfortunately one of the reasons I am trying to understand the cause here, is because the software I'm involved in building is deployed in many different places that use Windows 10, but I'm unlikely to get control over whether they're up to date with the most recent patches, etc.

Comment: For starters, the Windows type (Home, Pro etc) and the version (1809, 1903 etc) and anything else that you can think of. But that's curiosity and may not help here.